# Google Drive Android API onChildrenRetrievedCallback

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm building an app and trying to view a PDF stored in a shared Google Drive folder in-app. I've already connected to the Drive and I have a GoogleApiClient already set up. Right now I'm querying the database and trying to handle the results, but I'm having trouble with this code:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "sample_pdf.pdf"),
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "application/vnd.google-apps.file")))
                .build();
Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query)
        .setResultCallback(new OnChildrenRetrievedCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onChildrenRetrieved(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        // Iterate over the matching Metadata instances in mdResultSet
    }
});
```

Android Studio is not able to resolve the class OnChildrenRetrievedCallback. I have imported the com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks package but I'm not sure what else to do here. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/********************************************************************
   * find file/folder in GOODrive
   * @param prnId   parent ID (optional), null searches full drive, "root" searches Drive root
   *                this is a String representation of DriveId (DriveId.encodeToString() 
   * @param titl    file/folder name (optional)
   * @param mime    file/folder mime type (optional)
   * @return        void (arraylist of found objects in callback)
   */
  static void find(String prnId, String titl, String mime) {

    // add query conditions, build query
    ArrayList<Filter> fltrs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (prnId != null){
      fltrs.add(Filters.in(SearchableField.PARENTS,
        prnId.equalsIgnoreCase("root") ?
          Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGAC).getDriveId() : DriveId.decodeFromString(prnId)));
    }
    if (titl != null) fltrs.add(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, titl));
    if (mime != null) fltrs.add(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, mime));
    Query qry = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(fltrs)).build();

    // fire the query
    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGAC, qry).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult rslt) {
        if (rslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
          MetadataBuffer mdb = null;
          try {
            mdb = rslt.getMetadataBuffer();
            for (Metadata md : mdb) {
              if (md == null || !md.isDataValid() || md.isTrashed()) continue;
              // collect files
              DriveId driveId = md.getDriveId();
              String dId = driveId.encodeToString();
              String mime = md.getMimeType();
              //.....
            }
          } finally { if (mdb != null) mdb.close(); }  // don't know if necessary
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Your mimeType filter doesn't look right, either. I suggest skipping the mimeType filter, search by name(title) only and double-check the mime type you're getting (the *md.getMimeType()* in the code above).

BEWARE! File name/title IS NOT UNIQUE IDENTIFIER in the GooDrive universe

ONE MORE BEWARE! You will not see the file if t was not created by your Android App (see GDAA supported SCOPES).

Good Luck